# jQuery post dynamic keys via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, post

I have an array which contains many keys/values that are generated dynamically, so I never know what data I am definitely posting. This means I can't use :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "php/addressMain.php", 
    data: {data: alldata},
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {}
});
```

As I never know what data will be. I am currently just converting it to a querystring and posting it as a `GET`, however what I really need is something that will convert my array to a `data` array for the AJAX post, as the querystring becomes too long.

Comment: Why not? (I'm going for 'comment of the day' here.)

Comment: Because the key names are dynamically generated, and how could I do it without using eval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've already been able to create a querystring, why not use the query string with POST since your issues seems to be the length limitation of GET?

Answer (score 1):

I think `$(...).serialize()` will be able to help you.

Comment: Care to elaborate? I tried serialize, and although it works fine and serializes it like I'd expect it to, how do I use this in the ajax request?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I follow what the issue is, but this should work for passing data.

```
var POSTdata = [1,2,3,4];
$.ajax({
  url: "php/addressMain.php", 
  data: { data: POSTdata },
  type: "POST",
  success: function(data) {}
});
```

Then in PHP you should have this:

```
$_POST['data'] 
// should be = array( 1, 2, 3, 4)
```

The same is true if POSTdata = {key: value, key2: value2}
Then $_POST['data'] == array( 'key' => 'value', 'key2' => 'value2' )

Comment: Good example, data wasn't posted via PHP though.

Comment: You mean $_POST['data'] was empty? Could you have your addressMain.php do a print_r($_POST) and add an alert in your success function to look to see what is set?

Comment: $_POST['data'] never existed, the `alldata` was populated via javascript from existing elements/inputs on the page